# Changing String Color in Java

Tags: java, swing, colors, jtextarea

I want to change the color of the string I found from user input in `JTextArea`. I have been searching through internet but couldn't find a solution. I know JTextPane can handle such kind of styling very easily but I am not familiar with `JTextPane` and its functions. for example I don't know how to enable word-wrap and line-wrap which I can easily do in a text area.

So is there a way to change the color of a string in `JTtextArea`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either you use a JEditorPane which can take multiple fonts and formats or you set the Background/Foreground colour of your text area.

```
setForeground(Color Object Here);
setBackground(Color Object Here);
```